# How to hide the circle in radiobutton?

Tags: java-me

I want to create a ChoiceGroup of type EXCLUSIVE. The elements of this group are Images , and I want only the Image displayed. So how to hide the circle of the radiobutton ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually tried to do so, but i could give a good guess that this isn't possible
because there is no `paint()` or other method that you cant override to do so, and the class
it self doesn't provide for this behavior.